# skip before_action in controller when routes are nested in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have routes like this. I have nested batches routes with streams.

```
resources :batches

  resources :streams do
    resources :batches do
      collection do
        post 'create_batch'
      end
    end
  end
```

When i go to the link.

```
create_batch_stream_batches_path(stream)
```

In bacthesControlller.rb it calls for before action :set_batch which it should not as the before_action

```
before_action :set_batch, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def create_batch
    logger.info params
    binding.pry

  end
```

I tried with `skip_before_action` for `create_batch` but it didn't work.

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nested route, you can simply pass a custom parameter, which will be passed on to the controller during a request:

```
resources :batches
  resources :streams do
    resources :batches, skip: true do
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller you check whether the parameter is passed, and don't run the hook if the flag is set:

```
before_action :set_batch, unless: -> { params[:skip] }
```